# How to access specific subarray element?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get a value from an array the array is made like this

```
$resultOfAdd[“CaseAndMatterResult”][“ResultInfo”][“ReturnCode”];
```

and it gives an output of this

```
Array (
    [AddCaseAndMatterResult] => Array (
        [ResultInfo] => Array (
            [ReturnCode] => OK
            [Errors] =>
            [Warnings] =>
        )
        [CaseID] => 4880062
        [MatterID] => 4950481
        [LeadID] => 0
        [CustomerID] => 0
    )
)
```

All I want to do is put the part "MatterID" into a variable. how would I achieve this.

I have tried

```
$matterID = array($resultOfAdd["MatterID"]);
```

and this does not work.

Comment: The string "does not work" is not a built-in error message in PHP.

Comment: True, but the question was clear in intent and method. Far better candidates for vote-down, I reckon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multi-dimensional, associative array. Think of it like floors of a building. The key `MatterID` does not live in the first dimension (floor), rather on the second, in the `AddCaseAndMatterResult` sub-array.

```
$matterID = $resultOfAdd['AddCaseAndMatterResult']['MatterID']
```

Successive dimensions of an array are specified with successive square-brackets, each naming the key to look in (this is true of most languages).

Answer (score 1):

```
$matterID = $yourArray['AddCaseAndMatterResult']['MatterID'];
```

Comment: the array is $resultOfAdd not $resultof?

Comment: maybe... doesnt matter, the index is AddCase[..].. and not Case[..] so he writes about two diffrent arrays anyway...but it shows how to get it..

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
$matterID = $resultOfAdd['AddCaseAndMatterResult']['MatterID'];
```